# Post url for a registration app

Tags: ios, nsurl

I tried to insert some text from some string variables from a text field and the following error is shown.

`Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 9`

This is the code that I have Used.

```
NSURL *Registerurl;
Registerurl= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://xfgfgx.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@&email=%@&password=%@&address_1=%@&address_2=%@&city=%@&state=%@&zip=%@&action=signup",regisrationdetails.firstname,regisrationdetails.lastname,regisrationdetails.email,regisrationdetails.address1,regisrationdetails.address2,regisrationdetails.city,regisrationdetails.state,regisrationdetails.zip];
```

Is there some other format to enter extra text from the string variables shown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **NSString stringWithFormat** like shown below

```
NSURL *Registerurl;
Registerurl= [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xfgfgx.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@&email=%@&password=%@&address_1=%@&address_2=%@&city=%@&state=%@&zip=%@&action=signup",regisrationdetails.firstname,regisrationdetails.lastname,regisrationdetails.email,regisrationdetails.address1,regisrationdetails.address2,regisrationdetails.city,regisrationdetails.state,regisrationdetails.zip ]];
```

One more thing, use naming convention like **registerUrl** instead of **Registerurl**